# Compiling For 64bit Architecture in Ubuntu 32bit

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, ld

I'm looking for tutorial how to compile project for 64bit architecture in ubuntu 32 bit architecture. I have to put this project on shared hosting machine which is x86_64 architecture. I can't compile this project on remote machine because I didn't have permissions to install some dependencies for this project.

When I try to put compiled project from my computer (ubuntu 32 bit) the execution fails because of floating point exceptions. The same scenario with simple hello_world application.

I'm total beginner with gcc, ld and I was always using compiled packages but now I have to compile for target machine different than mine.

For now I figured out that I need to install g++-multilib and add to CCFLAGS -m64 to the gcc.

Now I have errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libc.so when searching for -lc
```

Is there any way to compile dependency libraries inside aplication so I didn't have to resolve dependency libraries on the remote machine.

Comment: Do you have a 64 bits processor? Can't you install a 64 bits distribution, and use a 32 bits `chroot` subsystem for your 32 bits specific things? If you don't have a 64 bits processor (e.g. only an old ATOM netbook) you may be in trouble (because emulating 64 bits machines on a 32 bits processor is painful and slow).

Comment: On Remote Machine there is Intel Xeon E5620 with 4 cores and x86_64 linux. On my laptop there is old Pentium IV not 64bit. I only want to compile the project and copy to the server and run it there. I don't want to run compiled project on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a 64-bit library pack.

```
apt-get install ibc6-dev-amd64
```

or something close to that (I used to have an Ubuntu machine at work, but I'm using Fedora at home, so can't even attempt to try what I'm suggesting - I know the principle is correct, but the exact detail is a bit vague)

Comment: This probably works only on a 64 bits processor with a 64 bits kernel. Then, having a 64 bits distribution is sensible (and use a `chroot`-ed, maybe `debootstrap`-ed, 32 bits distribution inside).

Comment: Whilst it's been a while, as long as the compiler (and assembler and linker) are built to compile 64-bit, it should be fine to compile and build on a 32-bit machine. That's how I and a group of others used to build the first 64-bit kernel when AMD first brought out the 64-bit processors. Building a kernel is harder than building an executable. Of course, for the 64-bit binary to be of any use, you need a 64-bit OS on a 64-bit processor, so why not compile it via ssh or similar on that machine?